# Finding smallest float in file then printing that and line above it

Tags: python, python-2.7, min

My data file looks like this:

```
3.6-band 
6238
Over
0.5678
Over
0.6874
Over
0.7680
Over
0.7834
```

What I want to do is to pick out the smallest float and the word directly above it and print those two values. I have no idea what I'm doing. I've tried

```
df=open('filepath')
  for line in df:
    df1=line.split()
    df2=min(df1)
```

Which is my attempt at at least trying to isolate the smallest float. Problem is it's just giving me the last value. I think that's a problem with python not knowing to start over with the iteration, but again...no idea what I'm doing. I tried `df2=min(df1.seek(0))` with no success, got an error saying `no attribute seek`. So that's what I've tried so far, I still have no idea how to print the row that would come before the smallest float. Suggestions/help/advice would be appreciated, thanks.

As a side note: this data file is an example of a larger one with similar characteristics, but the word 'Over' could also be 'Under', that's why I need to have it printed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the items in a list of lists,`[word,num]` pairs and then apply `min` on that list of list. Use `key` parameter of `min` to specify the which item must be used for comparison of item.:

```
with open('abc') as f:
    lis = [[line.strip(),next(f).strip()] for line in f]
    minn = min(lis, key = lambda x: float(x[1]))
    print "\n".join(minn)
...     
Over
0.5678
```

Here `lis` looks like this:

```
[['3.6-band', '6238'], ['Over', '0.5678'], ['Over', '0.6874'], ['Over', '0.7680'], ['Over', '0.7834']]
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I'd prefer it to be more in the format of unutbu's output though. Thanks in any case. This is good to know as a newbie.

Comment: @Matt you can simply do `print "\n".join(minn)` to get that output.

Comment: Hmmm...there's so much to pick up on. After reading the docs for unutbu's solution I think I prefer yours as it is a little easier to grasp at my level.

Comment: Why do you call your list `lis`, atleast call it `l` or `my_list` if you're too lazy to name it after its content. Also, `minn`? Why not `smallest` or `minimum`? Good answer and I +1'd, but that's just terrible naming.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), `izip(*[iterator]*2)` to cluster the lines in `df` into groups of 2. Then, to find the minimum *pair* of lines, use [`min` and its `key` parameter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) to specify the proxy to used for comparison. In this case, for every pair of lines, `(p, l)`, we want to use the float of the second line, `float(l)`, as the proxy:

```
import itertools as IT
with open('filepath') as df:
    previous, minline = min(IT.izip(*[df]*2), 
                            key=lambda (p, l): float(l))
    minline = float(minline)
    print(previous)
    print(minline)
```

prints

```
Over

0.5678
```

---

**An explanation of the grouper recipe:**

To understand the grouper recipe, first look at what happens if `df` were a list:

```
In [1]: df = [1, 2]

In [2]: [df]*2
Out[2]: [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

In Python, when you multiply a list by a positive integer `n`, you get `n` (shallow)
copies of the items in the list. Thus, `[df]*2` makes a list with two copies of `df` inside.

Now consider `zip(*[df]*2)`

The `*` used in `zip(*...)` has a special meaning. It tells Python to unpack the list following the `*` into arguments to be passed to `zip`. Thus, `zip(*[df]*2)` is exactly equivalent to `zip(df, df)`:

```
In [3]: zip(df, df)
Out[3]: [(1, 1), (2, 2)]

In [4]: zip(*[df]*2)
Out[4]: [(1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

[A more complete explanation of argument unpacking is given by SaltyCrane here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).

Take note of [what `zip` is doing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).
`zip(*[df]*2)` peels off the first element of both copies, (both 1's in this case),
and forms the tuple, (1,1). Then it peels off the second element of both copies, (both 2's), and forms the tuple (2,2). It returns a list with these tuples inside.

Now consider what happens when `df` is an iterator. An iterator is sort of like a list, except an iterator is good for only a single pass. As items are pulled out the iterator, the iterator can never be rewound.

For example, a file handle is an iterator.
Suppose we have a file with lines

```
1
2
3
4

In [8]: f = open('data')
```

You can pull items out of the iterator `f` by calling `next(f)`:

```
In [9]: next(f)
Out[9]: '1\n'

In [10]: next(f)
Out[10]: '2\n'

In [11]: next(f)
Out[11]: '3\n'

In [12]: next(f)
Out[12]: '4\n'
```

Each time we call `next(f)`, we get the next line from the file handle, `f`.
If we call `next(f)` again, we'd get a StopIteration exception, indicating the iterator is empty.

Now let's see how the grouper recipe behaves on `f`:

```
In [14]: f = open('data')  # Notice we have to open the file again, since the old iterator is empty

In [15]: [f]*2
Out[15]: 
[<open file 'data', mode 'r' at 0xa028f98>,
 <open file 'data', mode 'r' at 0xa028f98>]
```

`[f]*2` gives us a list with two *identical* copies of the same iterator `f`.

```
In [16]: zip(*[f]*2)
Out[16]: [('1\n', '2\n'), ('3\n', '4\n')]
```

`zip(*[f]*2)` peels off the first item from the first iterator, `f`, and then
peels off the first item form the second iterator, `f`. **But the iterator is the
same `f` both times!** And since iterators are good for a single-pass (you can
never go back), you get *different* items each time you peel off an item. `zip` is
calling `next(f)` each time to peel off an item.  So the first tuple is
`('1\n', '2\n')`. Likewise, `zip` then peels off the next item from the first
iterator `f`, and the next item from the second iterator `f`, and forms the
tuple `('3\n', '4\n')`. Thus, `zip(*[f]*2)` returns
`[('1\n', '2\n'), ('3\n', '4\n')]`.

That's really all there is to the grouper recipe. Above, I chose to use `IT.izip` instead of `zip` so that Python would return an iterator instead of a list of tuples. This would save a lot of memory if the file had a lot of lines in it. The difference between `zip` and `IT.izip` is explained more fully [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826/190597).

Comment: This looks nice. Can you explain line 3 to me? I'd like to understand what's going on, especially with the wildcards. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I just noticed the docs link. I'll read that first.

Comment: The grouper recipe you spread around is really great! It really nicely combines a lot of familiar python concepts.

Comment: Why isn't `b=range(16); list(zip(*[b]*4))` not dividing it? I wouldn't expect duplicates? (in Python 3)

Comment: @PascalvKooten: `range` is not a one-pass iterator. (See the error message raised by `next(b)`.) To fix, use `list(zip(*[iter(b)]*4))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use:

```
min(number)
```

You can only use:

```
min(num1, num2)
```

If your file looks like this:

```
6238
0.5678
0.6874
0.7680
0.7834
```

You can use this code:

```
Num1 = float(file.readline())

for line in file:
    Num2 = float(line)
    Num1 = min(Num1, Num2)
```

If you have the `"Over"`s then you can skip every second line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read all lines of the file, perhaps with File.readlines(), or a loop like you already have, and then for each line read the number (if it is a number) and compare to the "best so far" value.

It looks like you don't really need split().  What you do need to do, is check if each lines starts with a digit. If so, you can get the number with float(line).  Maybe float(line.strip()) if whitespace is causing trouble.  If the line doesn't start with a digit, keep it in a temporary variable.  If the next line proves to offer a lower number than the best-so-far value, you can copy that temporary value into a variable for the tentative output.

Answer (score 0):

I see some interesting solutions above. I would go for this straightforward solution. There is one problem left, which is that integers might be taken like this as well. Anyone a solution for this?

```
    df=open('myfile.txt')
    lines=df.readlines()
    minval = 1e99
    for n,line in enumerate(lines):
        try: 
            val=float(line)  # NB! like this, also integers will be taken. 
            if val < minval:  
                minval = val
                i_min  = n  
        except:
            pass
    word = lines[i_min-1]
```