# Parsing with BeautifulSoup Python with dynamic link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to parse table information listed on this site:

```
https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml;jsessionid=7A651D7E9437F76904BEC5623DBAB055?specId=19118104#expiry
```

This is the following code I'm using:

```
link = re.findall(re.compile('<a href="(.*?)">'), str(row))
link = 'https://www.theice.com'+link[0]
print link #Double check if link is correct
user_agent = 'Mozilla/20.0.1 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent}
req = urllib2.Request(link, headers = headers)
try:
    pg = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    page = BeautifulSoup(pg)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print 'Error:', e.code, '\n', '\n'

table = page.find('table', attrs = {'class':'default'})
tr_odd = table.findAll('tr', attrs = {'class':'odd'})
tr_even = table.findAll('tr', attrs = {'class':'even'})
print tr_odd, tr_even
```

For some reason, during the `urllib2.urlopen(req).read()` step, the link changes, i.e., the `link` doesn't contain the same url as the one provided above. Therefore, my program opens a different page and the variable `page` stores information form this new, different site. Thus, my `tr_odd` and `tr_even` variables are NULL.

What could be the reason for the link changing? Is there another way to access the contents of this page? All I need are the table values.

Comment: What do you mean "the link changes"? Does the `link` variable change its value? How do you see this happening? Did you add another `print link` on the next line and see that it's different?

Comment: I mean, the link is not the same. For example, if I copy that link (after the print statement) I can visit the correct website. But, when the program runs, it doesn't go to that same website. It's very strange.

Comment: The link is not the same as what? As itself? You're still not making yourself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information in this page is being supplied by a JavaScript function. When you download the page with `urllib` you get the page *before* the JavaScript is executed. When you view the page in a standard browser manually, you see the HTML *after* the JavaScript has been executed.

To get at the data programmatically, you need to use some tool that can execute JavaScript. There are a number of 3rd party options available for Python, such as [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), [WebKit](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/), or [spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/).

Here is an example of how to scrape the page using selenium (with [phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/)) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import lxml.html as LH
link = 'https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml;jsessionid=7A651D7E9437F76904BEC5623DBAB055?specId=19118104#expiry'

with contextlib.closing(webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')) as driver:
    driver.get(link)
    content = driver.page_source
    doc = LH.fromstring(content)
    tds = doc.xpath(
        '//table[@class="default"]//tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"]/td/text()')
    print('\n'.join(map(str, zip(*[iter(tds)]*5))))
```

yields

```
('Jul13', '2/11/13', '7/26/13', '7/26/13', '7/26/13')
('Aug13', '2/11/13', '8/30/13', '8/30/13', '8/30/13')
('Sep13', '2/11/13', '9/27/13', '9/27/13', '9/27/13')
('Oct13', '2/11/13', '10/25/13', '10/25/13', '10/25/13')
...
('Aug18', '2/11/13', '8/31/18', '8/31/18', '8/31/18')
('Sep18', '2/11/13', '9/28/18', '9/28/18', '9/28/18')
('Oct18', '2/11/13', '10/26/18', '10/26/18', '10/26/18')
('Nov18', '2/11/13', '11/30/18', '11/30/18', '11/30/18')
('Dec18', '2/11/13', '12/28/18', '12/28/18', '12/28/18')
```

---

**Explanation of the XPath:**

`lxml` allows you to select tags using [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). 
The XPath

```
'//table[@class="default"]//tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"]/td/text()'
```

means

```
//table    # search recursively for <table>
  [@class="default"]  # with an attribute class="default"
  //tr     # and find inside <table> all <tr> tags
    [@class="odd" or @class="even"]   # that have attribute class="odd" or class="even"
    /td      # find the <td> tags which are direct children of the <tr> tags  
      /text()  # return the text inside the <td> tag
```

---

**Explanation of `zip(*[iter(tds)]*5)`:**

The `tds` is a list. It looks something like

```
['Jul13', '2/11/13', '7/26/13', '7/26/13', '7/26/13', 'Aug13', '2/11/13', '8/30/13', '8/30/13', '8/30/13',...]
```

Notice that each row of the table consists of 5 items. But our list is flat. So, to group every 5 items together into a tuple, we can use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). `zip(*[iter(tds)]*5)` is an application of the grouper recipe. It takes a flat list, like `tds`, and turns it into a list of tuples with every 5 items grouped together.

Here is an [explanation of how the grouper recipe works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516752/190597). Please read that and if you have any question about it, I'll be glad to try to answer.

---

**To get just the first column of the table**, change the XPath to:

```
tds = doc.xpath(
    '''//table[@class="default"]
         //tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"]
           /td[1]/text()''')
print(tds)
```

---

For example,

```
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import lxml.html as LH
link = 'https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=6753474#expiry'
with contextlib.closing(webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')) as driver:
    driver.get(link)
    content = driver.page_source
    doc = LH.fromstring(content)
    tds = doc.xpath(
        '''//table[@class="default"]
             //tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"]
               /td[1]/text()''')
    print(tds)
```

yields

```
['Jul13', 'Aug13', 'Sep13', 'Oct13', 'Nov13', 'Dec13', 'Jan14', 'Feb14', 'Mar14', 'Apr14', 'May14', 'Jun14', 'Jul14', 'Aug14', 'Sep14', 'Oct14', 'Nov14', 'Dec14', 'Jan15', 'Feb15', 'Mar15', 'Apr15', 'May15', 'Jun15', 'Jul15', 'Aug15', 'Sep15', 'Oct15', 'Nov15', 'Dec15']
```

---

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain your last 2 lines of code?

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, but suppose I was only interested in the first column, i.e.: `Jul13, Aug13, Sep13...`, how should I make changes `zip(*[iter(tds)]*1)`?

Comment: Also, after step `content = driver.page_source`, is it possible to parse it to `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: Yes, it is. (Sorry to have changed that on you; I just like lxml better.)

Comment: No problem, the more the merrier, also I'm running Python 2.7 and I seem to get an error in the `with` statement: `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 63, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.", e)
WebDriverException: Message: 'Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available via screen`

Comment: When you install phantomjs, you get an executable named `phantomjs`. You need to change the string in `webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')` to the path to the phantomjs executable: `webdriver.PhantomJS('/path/to/executable'))`. `phantomjs` gives you a headless browser. I use it so I don't have to see Firefox pop up. If you don't want to install phantomjs, you can use `webdriver.Ie()` to get Internet Explorer if you already have Internet Explorer installed.

Comment: [The source code in service.py](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.html) shows you get the error message `Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver` when an exception is raised on `subprocess.Popen(self.service_args,..)`. This line is starting the phantomjs binary. So it looks like you either [need to install phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/download.html), or give a full path to the binary (as mentioned above) or just use `webdriver.Ie()` or `webdriver.Firefox()` or `webdriver.Chrome()` (if you have one of those browsers installed).

Comment: Thanks for all the help, the program works perfectly, but I have a few questions. Sorry, I'm still a beginner at Python, so I will ask some stupid ones. 1) I don't understand your `with ` command, how did this help with loading the java script. 2) What was the exe for? It looks like every time I run a link, a black command box will open up. 3) Is there a fundamental difference between lxml and beautifulsoup, should I use one over other?

Comment: The `with` statement sets up a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers). The reason why I chose to use one here is to guarantee that `driver.close()` is called when Python leaves the `with`-suite. Sure, you could forego the `with blahblahblah`, and just use `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')`, but then you'd have to remember to call `driver.close()` yourself and make sure under all conditions (including exceptions) that Python calls `driver.close()`. Instead of being bothered with that, the "best practice" is to use a `with` statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about in the second question. I suppose you mean phantomjs.exe? It gives you a headless browser. What code are you using to "run a link"? Is the black command box a Windows console? If so, I'm afraid I won't be able to help you; it sounds like a Windows thing, and I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: lxml and beautifulsoup are both HTML/XML parsers. beautifulsoup is written largely in Python, while lxml is a wrapper around the C library libxml2 and libxslt. [`lxml` is much faster than `beautifulsoup`](http://www.crummy.com/2012/01/22/0). The advantage of `beautifulsoup` is that has a more forgiving parser which can sometimes parse broken HTML. However, [beautifulsoup can use the lxml parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), and [lxml can use the beautifulsoup parser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html).

Comment: So if you install both, you can use either for parsing. Then it just becomes a choice between what API you like better for navigating HTML/XML. I prefer `lxml` because `XPath` is more compact than beautifulsoup's API. [XPath takes a while to learn](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) but in the end I think it is simpler than memorizing the multitude of methods Beautifulsoup makes available: findAll ,findPrevious, findNext, nextSibling, previousSibling, nextElement, find_parents, find_next_sibling, find_previous_siblings, find_all_next, ... blech; it's just too much!

Comment: There are other differences too. Lxml handles namespaces, XSLT, sax handlers, DTD validation, BeautifulSoup (I think) does not.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation, could you provide the code for the `try` `finally` clauses the `with` statement incorporates.

Comment: Something like this? `with ... as driver BLCOK` = `driver.__enter__() try: BLOCK finally: driver.__exit__()`

Comment: Sure. The `try..finally` is the one [shown here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing). You may also find [this explanation (by Fredrik Lundh)](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) useful.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to clarify my understanding. In `with contextlib.closing('link') as driver`, the decorator is `contextmanager` which takes `context.closing()` function as an argument. And that function is defined to with a `try` (which probably opens the link) and `finally` (which closes the link) ?

Comment: I think what is confusing is that there are two ways to define a contextmanager. Any object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods is a contextmanager. But you can also define a contextmanager by writing a generator function and wrapping it with the `@contextmanager` decorator. ["At the point where the generator yields, the block nested in the with statement is executed."](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager). When Python leaves the `with`-block either normally or due to an exception, execution resumes at the `yield` expression.

Comment: In `with contextlib.closing(webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')) as driver`, `contextlib.closing` is a decorator which takes `webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')` as an argument. `contextlib.closing` returns a `contextmanager` -- i.e. an object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. The actual definition of `contextlib.closing` can be [seen here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/86cc1983a94d/Lib/contextlib.py#l132). The documentation explains the behavior of `contextlib.closing` using a `try..finally` statement. But as you can see, the actual code just uses `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't `contextmanager` the decorator and `context.closing()` the wrapper and `webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')` the object being passed? This stuff is very new/confusing for me!

Comment: Sorry, I've been typing the word wrong. A [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) (2 words) is an object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. The [contextlib.contextmanager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) is a decorator which turns a generator function into a `context manager`. Above, everywhere I wrote `contextmanager` I meant `context manager`. When I wanted to refer to the decorator I wrote `@contextmanager`.

Comment: I've been calling `contextlib.closing` a decorator. But on further reflection, I should really have been calling it something else, because it is not used to decorate functions. Instead, [`contextlib.closing` is a class](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/86cc1983a94d/Lib/contextlib.py#l132). This class defines `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. Instances of `contextlib.closing` are `context managers`. `webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')` is the object being passed to `contextlib.closing`. Its `close` method is guaranteed to get called when Python leaves the `with`-suite.

Comment: Thanks for all the clear up, looking at this link: `http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing`, in `def closing(thing):` is the `thing` `page` or is it `line`? So when we get to the step `yield thing`, what is being iterated through, the `line` right?

Comment: `thing` is `urllib.urlopen('http://www.python.org')`. After `yield thing`, `page` is assigned the value `urllib.urlopen('http://www.python.org')`.

Comment: Thanks again for all the clear up. I'll need to spend another few days reviewing/googling to get a better understanding of generators/decorators/Context Managers. Going back to your code, the `tds = doc.xpath(...)` method doesn't work for this site specifically for link: `https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml;jsessionid=106A2FB63BB67E82AC398396DF4F66F7?specId=6753474#expiry`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Remove the `jsessionid`. Try: `link = 'https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=6753474#expiry'`.

Comment: Hey, I tried it without the `jsessionid` and it still didn't work.

Comment: Hm, that's odd! I've edited my post to show the code I am using with this link as the result.

Comment: Hey, if you don't mind, could you check this question please: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953580/parsing-with-lxml-xpath`

Comment: Hey, I just installed Ubuntu on my computer, I can get the code above to run properly, the only difference is that you don't mention the path of the `phantomjs` in your code while I do: `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs`. What can I do to change this?

Comment: By default, `/usr/local/bin` should be in your `PATH` environment variable. If that is true, you should be able to use the string `'phantomjs'` instead of the full path. You can check if `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH` by typing `echo $PATH` in a terminal, or by simplying typing `phantomjs` and seeing if you get a `phantomjs>` prompt. If `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `PATH`, see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) for info on setting "System-wide environment variables". Note: `/usr/local/bin` should already be listed in `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the link is actually changing.

Anyway, the problem is that your regex is wrong. If you take the links it prints out and paste it into a browser, you get a blank page, or the wrong page, or a redirect to the wrong page. And Python is going to download the exact same thing.

Here's a link from the actual page:

```
<a href="/productguide/MarginRates.shtml;jsessionid=B53D8EF107AAC5F37F0ADF627B843B58?index=&amp;specId=19118104" class="marginrates"></a>
```

Here's what your regex finds:

```
/productguide/MarginRates.shtml;jsessionid=B53D8EF107AAC5F37F0ADF627B843B58?index=&amp;specId=19118104
```

Notice that `&amp;` there? You need to decode that to `&` or your URL is wrong. Instead of having a query-string variable `specId` with value `19118104`, you've got a query-string variable `amp;specId` (although technically, you can't have unescaped semicolons like that either, so everything from `jsession` on is a fragment).

You'll notice that if you paste the first one into a browser, you get a blank page. I you remove the extra `amp;`, *then* you get the right page (after a redirect). And the same is true in Python.

Comment: Hi, if you run my code, and execute the `print` statement, you will see this link: `https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml;jsessionid=7A651D7E9437F76904BEC5623DBAB055?specId=19118104#expiry`. Which is the correct website. However, there are 2 similar sites: `https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=19118104#data` and `https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=19118104#` I think my program automatically goes to the last link.

Comment: I don't have your code, only the fragment of it that you provided, so I can't run it. Meanwhile, if I download the page manually and run your regexp against it, I get all kinds of things like `#" class="btn`, `/changePassword" style="float:left;clear:left;`, `/publicdocs/futures_us/ICE_Monthly_Softs_Fast_Facts.pdf" target="_blank`, etc. I can't guess which one of these is "the link" that you're expecting to work unless you tell me.

Comment: Actually… the first result is `/`. So, if that's a fragment of your real code (why would you use `findall` just to throw away all but the first one?), I _can_ guess the link. It's just `/`. Which is nothing like what you say it is.