# Zip together n number of lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to display a list in vertically sorted columns with number of columns decided by the user. I want to use `zip()` but I can't seem to figure out how to tell it to go through `n` no of lists.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random

lst = random.sample(range(100), 30)
lst = sorted(lst)

col_size = int(raw_input('How many columns do you want?: '))
sorting = 'Vertical'

if sorting == 'Vertical':
    # vertically sorted
    columns = []
    n = len(lst)//col_size

    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        columns.append(lst[i:i+n])

    print '\nVertically Sorted:'

    print columns
    print zip(*columns)
```

This gives this result:

```
How many columns do you want?: 4

Vertically Sorted:
[[0, 2, 4, 11, 12, 16, 23], [24, 31, 32, 36, 41, 48, 50], [52, 54, 61, 62, 63, 64, 67], [76, 80, 81, 89, 91, 92, 94], [96, 97]]
[(0, 24, 52, 76, 96), (2, 31, 54, 80, 97)]
```

If I knew the number of columns (e.g. 4), I could've coded:

```
for c1, c2, c3, c4 in zip(columns[0], columns[1], columns[2], columns[3]):
    print str(c1), str(c2).rjust(8), str(c3).rjust(8), str(c4).rjust(8)
```

But since I don't, how do I use `zip`? As you can see I tried `zip(*columns)` but that failed due to unequal no. of items in the last list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) `IT.izip_longest(*[iterable]*n)` to collect the items in `lst` into groups of size `n`. (See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516752/190597) for a more detailed explanation of how the grouper recipe works.)

```
import random
import itertools as IT
# lst = random.sample(range(100), 30)
lst = range(30)
lst = sorted(lst)

col_size = int(raw_input('How many columns do you want?: '))
sorting = 'Vertical'

if sorting == 'Vertical':
    # vertically sorted
    n = len(lst)//col_size
    lst = iter(lst)
    columns = IT.izip_longest(*[lst]*n, fillvalue='')

    print '\nVertically Sorted:'

    print('\n'.join(
        [''.join(map('{:4}'.format, row))
         for row in IT.izip(*columns)]))
```

yields

```
   0   7  14  21  28
   1   8  15  22  29
   2   9  16  23    
   3  10  17  24    
   4  11  18  25    
   5  12  19  26    
   6  13  20  27
```

Answer (score 1):

Zip doesn't do what you're after because the rows are different sizes. Map will transpose when rows are uneven.

See the following with code help from [Create nice column output in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989334/create-nice-column-output-in-python).

### PROGRAM

import random

lst = random.sample(range(100), 30)
lst = sorted(lst)

col_size = int(raw_input('How many columns do you want?: '))
sorting = 'Vertical'

if sorting == 'Vertical':
    # vertically sorted
    columns = []
    n = len(lst)//col_size

```
for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
    columns.append(lst[i:i+n])

print '\nColumns:'
columns = map(None,*columns)
print columns
print '\nVertically Sorted:'

col_width = max(len(str(word)) for row in columns for word in row) + 2  # padding
for row in columns:
  print "".join(str(word).ljust(col_width) for word in row if word is not None)
```

### OUTPUT

```
How many columns do you want?: 4

Columns:
[(0, 19, 45, 62, 92), (1, 24, 47, 64, 93), (5, 29, 48, 72, None), (6, 31, 50, 80, None), (9, 34, 56, 85, None), (14, 36, 58, 87, None), (15, 37, 61, 90, None)]

Vertically Sorted:
0     19    45    62    92
1     24    47    64    93
5     29    48    72
6     31    50    80
9     34    56    85
14    36    58    87
15    37    61    90
```

Comment: In this ans, list is horizontally sorted. I want to sort it vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Extend last list with None elements to get equal length, zip, after remove None elements from result.