# create dictionary from list - in sequence

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary from list

```
>>> list=['a',1,'b',2,'c',3,'d',4]
>>> print list
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4]
```

I use dict() to produce dictionary from list
but the result is not in sequence as expected.

```
>>> d = dict(list[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(list),2))
>>> print d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

I expect the result to be in sequence as the list.

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Can you guys please help advise?

Comment: Keys in a dictionary are not ordered. Why do you expect this order? Because it's the same as in the list or because it is lexigographical? Maybe you don't need a dictionary. Can you add more informations about how you are going to use "d"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries don't have any order, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want the order to be preserved. And instead of using indices use an [`iterator`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator).

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> lis = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4]
>>> it = iter(lis)
>>> OrderedDict((k, next(it)) for k in it)
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip): `zip(*[iterable]*n)` to collect the items into groups of `n`:

```
In [5]: items = ['a',1,'b',2,'c',3,'d',4]

In [6]: items = iter(items)

In [7]: dict(zip(*[items]*2))
Out[7]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

PS. Never name a variable `list`, since it shadows the builtin (type) of the same name.

The grouper recipe is easy to use, but [a little harder to explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516752/190597).

Items in a `dict` are unordered. So if you want the dict items in a certain order, use a [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (as falsetru already pointed out):

```
In [13]: collections.OrderedDict(zip(*[items]*2))
Out[13]: OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
```

Comment: I'll just note that `items = iter(items)` could lead to subtle problems if `items` is expected to be used as a list later...

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary is an unordered data structure. To preserve order use [collection.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> lst = ['a',1,'b',2,'c',3,'d',4]
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(lst),2))
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
```