# Create Matrix from List within List

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I have the following list:

```
sortedList = [['2', 'f'],['5', 'B'],['8', '6'],['32','@'],['43', 'G'],['76', '.'],['173', 'v'],['200', '.'],['265', 'y']]
```

I am attempting to create a 3x3 matrix from this list so that the output would be the following:

```
matrix = [['f','B','6'],['@','G','.'],['v','.','y']]
```

Essentially, I need to find a function that would take the last string of each list and put it into lists 3 strings in length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to collect the last string in each item:

```
In [67]: [item[-1] for item in sortedList]
Out[67]: ['f', 'B', '6', '@', 'G', '.', 'v', '.', 'y']
```

Then, to collect these items in groups of 3, use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
In [68]: zip(*[(item[-1] for item in sortedList)]*3)
Out[68]: [('f', 'B', '6'), ('@', 'G', '.'), ('v', '.', 'y')]
```

Note that the grouper recipe, `zip(*[iterator]*3)` calls for an iterator, so the list comprehension was replaced by a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Comment: Wow, a generator inside an multiplied array, nice. But it might be unclear how it works.

Comment: I've tried to write an explanation of how the grouper recipe works [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17516752/190597), but I fear it is not very good.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Needed to have the user choose what to multiply by at the end, so I replaced "3" with a command line argument.